# More combination to expand grid function in R

Tags: r, grid, combinations

I have data as

```
subtype <- c("ar","sub")
height <- c("0","1")
```

I am using expand.grid(subtype,height) but I get

```
Var1    Var2
ar        0
sub       0
ar        1
sub       1
```

I need

```
Var1    Var2
ar       0
sub      1
ar       1
sub      0
ar       0
sub      0
ar       1
sub      1
```

Comment: Hm, can't figure out the pattern behind your desired output.

Comment: its (0,0) , (1,0), (0,1),(1,1) instead of (0,0),(1,1)

Comment: Yeah, the ordering is not consistent with any sorting rule that I can figure, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this gives the data you want (just in a different order)

```
cbind.data.frame(Var1=subtype , Var2=c(t(as.matrix(expand.grid(height,height)))))

#   Var1 Var2
# 1   ar    0
# 2  sub    0
# 3   ar    1
# 4  sub    0
# 5   ar    0
# 6  sub    1
# 7   ar    1
# 8  sub    1
```